# Coalescing (combining) callbacks in node.js 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, node-async, node-https

I'm working with an AWS lambda function that has a sort of 'map/reduce' feel to it. But the 'map' part of it, that is the part that does multiple calls is async.

Using the Node 6 STD lib, is there a dynamic way to get all results returned to a shared spot.

What I've thought about so far:

- `await async` is a great abstraction but isn't in node 6 to my knowledge, just node 8.
- `array.reduce` says it takes a callback but the structure of an http request seems not to qualify though I certainly may be wrong
- I've thought about a really suboptimal solution, where each callback puts into a shared queue or array. And I have a loop after all the requests that checks the length of the array - I don't like this solution though

Could you guys point me in the right direction or show me some code that would do this?

Comment: Convert all asynchronous functions to the functions that return promise, and use `Promise.all` to get all results.

Comment: @alexmac, thank will do! Any direction on what STD lib does http with promises, or a lib that converts callbacks to promises?

Comment: Node.js natively supports Promises, but there are some powerful promise libraries, such as Bluebird or Q. Bluebird has `promifiy` and `promisifyAll` methods to convert a single function or all functions to the promises.

Comment: Sounds good Alex, I'll post the final code here when I get it :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) is your friend.

To convert callback functions into promises you can use [`.promisify()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) or [`.fromCallback()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.fromcallback.html).

To do map/reduce over an array of promises, you can use [`.map()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) and [`.reduce()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reduce.html).